# jquery ajax post json doesn't work in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have this jquery code:

```
var sendInfo = {
    auth: {
        username: "janusz",
        password: "password"
    },
    func: "getCategories"
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://domainname/fcgi-bin/wgpa.fcgi',
    type: "POST",
    data: sendInfo,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "text/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        //....
    }
});
```

It works in Chrome, Firefox, IE11, but it fails in IE8.
Doesn't say anything. And the request doesn't appear on server side either.

Comment: jQuery does not support cross-origin Ajax in IE8. Instead of `XMLHttpRequest`, cross-origin requests in IE8 must be done with the Microsoft-specific `XDomainRequest` object, which has many weird rules and restrictions. The jQuery team decided not to support it.

Comment: use jsonp instead of json

Comment: @user8888 Can't POST with jsonp

Comment: @JasonP  oh yes i did not see that

Comment: possible duplicate of [cross-domain issue in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643839/cross-domain-issue-in-ie)

Comment: See also [CORS with jQuery and XDomainRequest in IE8/9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487216/cors-with-jquery-and-xdomainrequest-in-ie8-9)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you've resolved the issue. In case any other people hit this question, I'll provide an answer.

You can you use EasyXDM ( http://easyxdm.net ) for you cross domain posts. It can be a little bit tricky to set up, but works a charm.